# Why would someone go back and modify a question that’s months old and already has an accepted answer?

Tags: discussion

The post in question is here [Flex children not expanding to full height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38295191/flex-children-not-expanding-to-full-height) And it was edited moments ago and marked as a duplicate. The question was answered months ago and an accepted answer was selected. Am I missing something or is it pointless to go back and mark this as duplicate (or any other edits) at this point?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Stack Overflow questions aren't automatically [locked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post) because their age either because they have an accepted answer.

An old question might still be a good question nowadays and as such it is open for new answers and edits. The OP is able to unaccept the accepted answer or accept a different answer at any time.

An old question might be edited for many reasons. One might be because there are better tags or the tags use have changed over the time.

An old question might be marked as duplicate of a newer one because the newer is better some way, i.e., the newer might be more appropriate to serve as a canonical question.

Answer (score 16):

The age of the question is irrelevant. A question is never fully answered on Stack Overflow because a new answer can always be added. That's why it's important to pay attention to old questions just as much as the new ones. We need to edit and improve them so that they get the attention needed.

If the same question has better answers on another question, it's ok to close it as a duplicate. This will point people toward better answers.

The acceptance mark doesn't mean that the question is solved or closed. It just means that the person who asked the question preferred that answer.

Comment: "*The acceptance mark doesn't mean that the question is solved or closed. It just means that the person who asked the question preferred that answer.*" Well, it sorta _does_ mean that it is solved... at least for the person who asked the question. That's not the same thing as 'final, definitive answer', sure, but it is also not _not_ 'solved', either.